# How do I prevent Entity Framework from caching a property marked as: NotMapped?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a model with several properties. One of the properties is decorated with [NotMapped] as it is a calculated field. This field has to be calculated everytime. EF (5) is caching the result of the calculation and its there the next time the same ID is requested. It fails if the calculation determined it could not calculate anything and the value in the model should then be null, except it's not cause it will just have whatever value was calculated before.

Can I prevent the DBContext from attempting to hit the cache for non mapped properties?